# Searching API with query string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am currently building an API, I want to be able to search the API via the query string. So for example `http://api.dev/?q=12`

I can get the value entered but how do I then use this to search the database?

```
if ($q = Input::get('q'))
 {
  return( ModelName::where('id', '=', $q));
 }
```

This doesn't seem to change the search and the same data is just returned.

Answer (score 0):

ID's are unique so it doesn't surprise me you're getting the same result.

For Laravel I find the query builder to be better at handling search queries instead of Eloquent.
E.g.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
             ->where('votes', '>', 100)
             ->orWhere('name', 'John')
             ->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is just the same query as my Eloquent one and the same result, the data doesn't change.

Comment: Input::get() does return null if it cannot find the $_GET or $_POST variable. In your question you put http://api.dev/q=12. Shouldn't this be http://api.dev/?q=12 instead?

Comment: Yes this was just a typo.

Comment: try ModelName::where('id', '=', $q)->get() instead. Only the ::find() method doesn't need the get method added on. This is what's demonstrated in the laravel docs so I'm wondering how you are even getting a result. I don't have laravel install on this comp to test if the where doesn't need the get method or not. Other than that I'm out of ideas. Also, if your model uses the soft delete feature and the result you're looking for is marked deleted  then add withTrashed() before the where method too.

Answer (score 0):

To search from the db with Eloquent you can use both this ways:

```
ModelName::where('id', '=', $q)->get();
```

or

```
ModelName::find($q);
```

In the second example Laravel assumes that your Primary Key is `id`, so in case you have another field as your primary you have to overwrite it, by setting the property in the model.

```
class ModelName 
{
    ...your props
    private $primaryKey = 'yourPrimaryKey'
    ...
}
```